# Iterate over possibly empty lines in a way that matches the expectations of existing code

Tags: string, iterator, lua, pattern-matching

I used to iterate over lines in a string with a simple

```
for line in s:gmatch("[^\r\n]+") do
```

and that worked perfectly! Then real life happened....

.... and now my requirements have changed: I need to match on empty lines **too**. And here is the problem: since this form of iteration is used at several locations that are all jungles in their own right, I want to avoid changing the surrounding code as much as possible. My attempts with `gmatch`/`find` so far have not been able to create a 'drop in' replacement for the above pattern due to subtle expectations that the above functions have not been able to match.

The construct I seek (`for line in some_matcher(s) do`) matches the following requirements which I believe cover all the edge-cases I am worrying about:

```
   INPUT            EXPECTATIONS

1. ''            -- match once   ('')
2. '\r\n'        -- match twice  ('', '')
3. '\r\n\r\n'    -- match thrice ('', '', '')
4. 'aaa'         -- match once   ('aaa')
5. 'aaa\r\n'     -- match twice  ('aaa', '')
6. 'aaa\r\nbbb'  -- match twice  ('aaa', 'bbb')
7. '\r\nbbb'     -- match twice  ('', 'bbb')
```

My old solution assumes only `\r\n` line-endings happen, and it is completely fine if the new solution only handles that scenario.

However, since there's talk of plans for Linux support in my shop, an answer that also deals with the plainer `\n` line-ending (for future unix compatibility) would be very much appreciated and save a re-visit to this problem several months down the road. The **catch** however is that in many cases I require the **starting column of this match** in the original string input. If the above construct (`for ... do`) can output that as an added benefit, that would be especially awesome.

Comment: shouldn't \r\n\r\n match 4 times? since \r\n matches twice? or are you basically attempting to match everything around/between the newlines?

Comment: I am trying to match the stuff inbetween the newlines. I don't care about the (kind of) newline at all. I care about what is between them, and the starting positions of said 'matches'. Also see the initial gmatch() pattern at the top of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to accurately detect newline boundaries rather than skip/discard them, in a cross platform way, you can't use a set that includes both `\r` and `\n`, because it will match the newline sequence `\r\n` twice rather than once (CRLF is a single newline on DOS/Windows). You could handle this with a sufficiently powerful regular expression engine (e.g. supporting alternations), but Lua's pattern matching library is very minimal.

Your best bet is to normalize newlines before processing the text, something like this:

```
function normalize_eols(s)
    return s
        :gsub('\r\n','\n')
        :gsub('\r', '\n')
end
```

As for your input=>output grid, if we think of the newline as a line *separator*, then I would expect `[^\n]*` (zero or more non-newline characters) to work, but we get the following:

```
''         => ('')
'\n'       => ('', '')
'\n\n'     => ('', '', '')
'aaa'      => ('aaa', '')
'aaa\n'    => ('aaa', '', '')
'aaa\nbbb' => ('aaa', '', 'bbb', '')
'\nbbb'    => ('', 'bbb', '')
```

Frankly, I don't know why.

However, if we think of the newline as a line *terminator*, then we can get the results you want by appending a newline to the input and using the pattern `[^\n]*\n` (zero or more non-newline characters followed by a newline):

```
'\n'         => ('')
'\n\n'       => ('', '')
'\n\n\n'     => ('', '', '')
'aaa\n'      => ('aaa')
'aaa\n\n'    => ('aaa', '')
'aaa\nbbb\n' => ('aaa', 'bbb')
'\nbbb\n'    => ('', 'bbb')
```

So your code would change to this:

```
s = normalize_eols(s) .. '\n'
for line in s:gmatch('([^\n]*)\n') do
    ...
```

Comment: Normalizing the newlines beforehand does not provide an alternative; it messes up the indices at which the items start because 2 bytes become 1 in the Windows case, and 1 byte becomes 2 if I were to convert it to the Linux alternative. However, appending `"\r\n"` to s, and `gmatch("([^\r\n]*)\r\n")` seems to work for my Windows case, although I'll have to test it indepth before I accept the question. I suspect the best shot at Linux compatibility is by making the pattern variable, and using a function to append the extra terminator out of sight.

Comment: If you can't normalize newlines, you can detect which newline scheme is in use and use a different pattern for each, or use a more powerful regex library which supports alternations, or just write a custom lexer. However, the requirement of calculating specific offsets in a *text file* is extremely suspect. It would be interesting to hear what the actual problem being solved is.

Comment: It's not a text file; the string is the contents of a multi-line edit control. As those are context-sensitive and need to be highly scriptable (depending on which edit, what situation, etc), this is basically a minimal poor mans lexer as the different lines being like 'statements' is about the only real grammar that exists. The starting pos. makes it possible for the user-side scripting to support things as auto-completion with selections etc. TL;DR? Total lack of design, abuse of standard controls, can't do anything about that. I only need to maintain+hack stuff in once every so often.

Comment: The newline messiness is with regards to *text files*, not edit controls; find out what the edit control uses for newlines and you're done. I'm still not getting how the offsets within a string help you for things like auto-completion. Do you implement autocompletion by modifying the text and stuffing it back in the edit control? o.O Does the edit control not have a line-oriented API? What is this UI implemented in?